# Wants to understand traffic flow of Catalyst layer3 Switch 3850 . what are sequence this switch will check to delivery packet to destination

Tags: network, switching, network-core

i wants to know clear understanding about how Cisco layer3 switch checks in sequence order when traffic arrive to its L3 Interface . i want to know traffic flow in Cisco layer 3 switch ,because switch has ARP -table ,routing table access-list . which one it will check in order to delivery packet to destination . please help..

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

The order of operations can vary depending on the specific IOS version and the configuration, but here's a general idea from the [Cisco website](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/ip/network-address-translation-nat/6209-5.html).

Note that most L3 switches can't do NAT or IPSec.

1. If IPSec then check input access list
2. decryption - for CET (Cisco Encryption Technology) or IPSec
3. check input access list
4. check input rate limits
5. input accounting
6. redirect to web cache
7. policy routing
8. routing
9. NAT inside to outside (local to global translation)
10. crypto (check map and mark for encryption)
11. check output access list
12. inspect (Context-based Access Control (CBAC))
13. TCP intercept
14. encryption
15. Queueing